# application.css changed path when upgrading Rails 3.2.17 to Rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am upgrading `Rails 3.2.17` to `Rails 4.0.0` and my app cannot retrieve it's assets anymore.

If I access the page source I can see that the app is trying to load the css from:

```
/stylesheets/jackapp/application.css?body=1
```

If I delete 'stylesheets' and I see the stylesheet at the following:

```
/jackapp/application.css?body=1
```

Same behaviour when trying to load application.js. It tries to get

```
/javascripts/jackapp/application.css?body=1
```

but instead the js is at:

```
/jackapp/application.css?body=1
```

Any idea? Why is Rails 4 appending 'stylesheet' to that path?

I did not change the `application.html.erb` that is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "print.css", media: "print" %>
    <title><%= yield :title %> - GOV.UK</title>
    <%= yield :head %>
  </head>
```

I've also removed the `group :assets` from the `Gemfile` and replaced

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(assets: %w(development test))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

with:

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```

In addition I've followed this instructions:

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4
```

And I do not have any failing test.

How can I tell the app to load the assets at the correct path?
Thanks.

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add a leading slash to the path where assets are compiled to the application.rb file

```
config.assets.prefix = "jackapp"
```

to:

```
config.assets.prefix = "/jackapp"
```

OOH.. RAILS.